# Moment problem for discrete distributions

Tags: pr.probability, polynomials

Let $x_1, \dots, x_N \in \mathbb R$ and consider the discrete distribution $\mu := \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{x_i}$, where $\delta_x$ denotes the Dirac measure, i.e. for any measurable set $B \subset \mathbb R$, we have $\delta_x(B) = 1$ if $x \in B$ and zero otherwise.

The definition of moments for discrete distribution is included in the general definition: In the case of discrete distributions, we have $\mathbb E(x^p) = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^p$.

I am interested in the (simple-looking) moment problem of determining $\mu$ from the moments $\mathbb E(x^p)$. In particular, is it true that $\mathbb E(x), \mathbb E(x^2), \dots, \mathbb E(x^N)$ determine $\mu$ uniquely?

Secondly, if the considered points are vectors, i.e. $x_i \in \mathbb R^n$, can I consider only $\mathbb E(x^\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a multi-index of the form $(0, \dots, p, \dots, 0)$ or must I consider all moments related to all multi-indices of a given degree $p$?

Comment: Yes. This is a corollary of some standard identities involving symmetric functions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Answer (score 3):

The answer for vectors uses the theory of multi-symmetric polynomials and in particular
power sums. You can learn about that in Emmanuel Briand's thesis mentioned in myprevious MO answer [Generalizing the Fundamental Theorem of Symmetric Polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89337/generalizing-the-fundamental-theorem-of-symmetric-polynomials/89410#89410)
Often people attibute the theory to Weyl (in his book on classical groups), however it is much older, with major contributions by Poisson, Schlaffli and Junker.

Answer (score 2):

The single-variable case is indeed easy, as pointed out in the comment.

The multivariate case has been studied by [Curto and Fialkow](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~rcurto/tcmp10new.pdf) and then M.Laurent gave a [more algebraic approach](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2005-133-10/S0002-9939-05-08133-5/home.html) to this.